# Multiple appearances of authors using apacite

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, apacite

And thanks beforehand for your help. I am trying to use the package apacite for writing an essay in TexMaker. Nevertheless, despite the fact I am following the instructions as supposed, at the end, in the References chapter names appear multiple times.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}

This statement requires citation \cite{Tanzi:1998}; this one does too \cite{Smith:2013jd}. Lorem ipsum dolor.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

My .bib file:

```
@incollection{Tanzi:1998,
  title={Corruption, public investment, and growth},
  author={Tanzi, Vito and Davoodi, Hamid},
  booktitle={The Welfare State, Public Investment, and Growth},
  pages={41--60},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@ARTICLE{Smith:2013jd,
    author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
    title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
    journal = {Journal title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-456},
    number = {52},
    month = {March},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}
```

And This is how the references are shown:
[image]
As you see the authors name appear like 3 times.

Any idea of what is going on?

Here is the entire code:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Thin Sectioned Essay
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (3/8/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original Author:
% Nicolas Diaz (nsdiaz@uc.cl) with extensive modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % Font size (can be 10pt, 11pt or 12pt) and paper size (remove a4paper for US letter paper)
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} % Better typography
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters
\linespread{1.5} % Change line spacing here, Palatino benefits from a slight increase by default

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}} % Change the square brackets for each bibliography item from '[1]' to '1.'
\renewcommand{\@listI}{\itemsep=0pt} % Reduce the space between items in the itemize and enumerate environments and the bibliography

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ % Customize the title - do not edit title and author name here, see the TITLE block below
\begin{flushright} % Right align
{\LARGE\@title} % Increase the font size of the title

\vspace{50pt} % Some vertical space between the title and author name

{\large\@author} % Author name
\\\@date % Date

\vspace{40pt} % Some vertical space between the author block and abstract
\end{flushright}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{\textbf{Unnecessarily Long Essay Title}\\ % Title
Focused and Deliciously Witty Subtitle} % Subtitle

\author{\textsc{Camilo Recio} % Author
\\{\textit{The University of Nottingham}}} % Institution

\date{\today} % Date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Print the title section

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT AND KEYWORDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary} % Uncomment to change the name of the abstract to something else

%\begin{abstract}
%Morbi tempor congue porta. Proin semper, leo vitae faucibus dictum, metus mauris lacinia lorem, ac congue leo felis eu turpis. Sed nec nunc pellentesque, gravida eros at, porttitor ipsum. Praesent consequat urna a lacus lobortis ultrices eget ac metus. In tempus hendrerit rhoncus. Mauris dignissim turpis id sollicitudin lacinia. Praesent libero tellus, fringilla nec ullamcorper at, ultrices id nulla. Phasellus placerat a tellus a malesuada.
%\end{abstract}
%
%\hspace*{3,6mm}\textit{Keywords:} lorem , ipsum , dolor , sit amet , lectus % Keywords
%
%\vspace{30pt} % Some vertical space between the abstract and first section

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ESSAY BODY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Introduction}

This statement requires citation \cite{Tanzi:1998}; this one does too \cite{Smith:2013jd}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean dictum lacus sem, ut varius ante dignissim ac. Sed a mi quis lectus feugiat aliquam. Nunc sed vulputate velit. Sed commodo metus vel felis semper, quis rutrum odio vulputate. Donec a elit porttitor, facilisis nisl sit amet, dignissim arcu. Vivamus accumsan pellentesque nulla at euismod. Duis porta rutrum sem, eu facilisis mi varius sed. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris rhoncus neque nisi, ut laoreet augue pretium luctus. Vestibulum sit amet luctus sem, luctus ultrices leo. Aenean vitae sem leo.

Nullam semper quam at ante convallis posuere. Ut faucibus tellus ac massa luctus consectetur. Nulla pellentesque tortor et aliquam vehicula. Maecenas imperdiet euismod enim ut pharetra. Suspendisse pulvinar sapien vitae placerat pellentesque. Nulla facilisi. Aenean vitae nunc venenatis, vehicula neque in, congue ligula.

Pellentesque quis neque fringilla, varius ligula quis, malesuada dolor. Aenean malesuada urna porta, condimentum nisl sed, scelerisque nisi. Suspendisse ac orci quis massa porta dignissim. Morbi sollicitudin, felis eget tristique laoreet, ante lacus pretium lacus, nec ornare sem lorem a velit. Pellentesque eu erat congue, ullamcorper ante ut, tristique turpis. Nam sodales mi sed nisl tincidunt vestibulum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

%------------------------------------------------

\section*{Section Name}

Cras gravida, est vel interdum euismod, tortor mi lobortis mi, quis adipiscing elit lacus ut orci. Phasellus nec fringilla nisi, ut vestibulum neque. Aenean non risus eu nunc accumsan condimentum at sed ipsum.
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth} % Inline image example
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{fish.png}
\end{center}
\caption{Fish}
\end{wrapfigure}
Aliquam fringilla non diam sed varius. Suspendisse tellus felis, hendrerit non bibendum ut, adipiscing vitae diam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla lobortis purus eget nisl scelerisque, commodo rhoncus lacus porta. Vestibulum vitae turpis tincidunt, varius dolor in, dictum lectus. Aenean ac ornare augue, ac facilisis purus. Sed leo lorem, molestie sit amet fermentum id, suscipit ut sem. Vestibulum orci arcu, vehicula sed tortor id, ornare dapibus lorem. Praesent aliquet iaculis lacus nec fermentum. Morbi eleifend blandit dolor, pharetra hendrerit neque ornare vel. Nulla ornare, nisl eget imperdiet ornare, libero enim interdum mi, ut lobortis quam velit bibendum nibh.

Morbi tempor congue porta. Proin semper, leo vitae faucibus dictum, metus mauris lacinia lorem, ac congue leo felis eu turpis. Sed nec nunc pellentesque, gravida eros at, porttitor ipsum. Praesent consequat urna a lacus lobortis ultrices eget ac metus. In tempus hendrerit rhoncus. Mauris dignissim turpis id sollicitudin lacinia. Praesent libero tellus, fringilla nec ullamcorper at, ultrices id nulla. Phasellus placerat a tellus a malesuada.

%------------------------------------------------

\section*{Conclusion}

Fusce in nibh augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In dictum accumsan sapien, ut hendrerit nisi. Phasellus ut nulla mauris. Phasellus sagittis nec odio sed posuere. Vestibulum porttitor dolor quis suscipit bibendum. Mauris risus lectus, cursus vitae hendrerit posuere, congue ac est. Suspendisse commodo eu eros non cursus. Mauris ultrices venenatis dolor, sed aliquet odio tempor pellentesque. Duis ultricies, mauris id lobortis vulputate, tellus turpis eleifend elit, in gravida leo tortor ultricies est. Maecenas vitae ipsum at dui sodales condimentum a quis dui. Nam mi sapien, lobortis ac blandit eget, dignissim quis nunc.

\begin{enumerate}
\item First numbered list item
\item Second numbered list item
\end{enumerate}

Donec luctus tincidunt mauris, non ultrices ligula aliquam id. Sed varius, magna a faucibus congue, arcu tellus pellentesque nisl, vel laoreet magna eros et magna. Vivamus lobortis elit eu dignissim ultrices. Fusce erat nulla, ornare at dolor quis, rhoncus venenatis velit. Donec sed elit mi. Sed semper tellus a convallis viverra. Maecenas mi lorem, placerat sit amet sem quis, adipiscing tincidunt turpis. Cras a urna et tellus dictum eleifend. Fusce dignissim lectus risus, in bibendum tortor lacinia interdum.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe. Did you recently change the citation management package and/or the bibliography style? If so, try deleting all aux files and recompiling from scratch, i.e., running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Hello Mico. I deleted all the aux files and recompiled as suggested and I am still getting the double authors appearance. I don't really know how to modify the citation management package so I don't believe I have done that. The same applies for the bibliography style. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: As I wrote earlier, I took your sample code, made it compilable, and most definitely did not encounter the issue you say you're grappling with. There must be something in your LaTeX document which you haven't disclosed yet that's causing the wayward behavior. Are you maybe loading other citation management packages (`natbib`, `cite`, `harvard`, `apalike`, `chicago`, etc are some candidates) *in addition to* the `apacite` package?

Comment: I decided the best thing to do is to completely copy the document I am using. I made it shorter before because I thought it was going to be a little bit tidier.

Comment: Try without `%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}} % Change the square brackets for each bibliography item from '[1]' to '1.'`

Answer (score 1):

The multiple appearance of the name is caused by `\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}}`. Without it, your bibliography looks fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{\textbf{#1.}} % Change the square brackets for each bibliography item from '[1]' to '1.'
%\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@incollection{Tanzi:1998,
  title={Corruption, public investment, and growth},
  author={Tanzi, Vito and Davoodi, Hamid},
  booktitle={The Welfare State, Public Investment, and Growth},
  pages={41--60},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@ARTICLE{Smith:2013jd,
    author = {Jones, A.~B. and Smith, J.~M.},
    title = {{A}rticle {T}itle},
    journal = {Journal title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {13},
    pages = {123-456},
    number = {52},
    month = {March},
    publisher = {Publisher}
}

\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

\cite{Tanzi:1998}
\cite{Smith:2013jd}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I would have never imagined it was causing it.

Comment: @Andrés: Do not say 'Thank you', accept the solution in order to appreciate the work done by users here